# Customized log entries using logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have a requirement where the log entries being written to log files need to be of specific format.

for eg:

> 2016-01-28 21:42:48,399 INFO
>   field1:value1;field2:value2;field3:value3;field4:value4

We are using logback for logging. The values of the fields are stored in a java object. Any suggestions or pointers on how to achieve this using custom appenders/layout or any other means would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to log the fields to your log file you should use the MDC(Mapped Diagnostic Context) system, it allows you to put the values in a map that will be used while logging, the official doc can be found [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, this appears to be working for my requirement as of now. :)